# automatic hyperref label

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, luatex, href

I want to have automatic labels when using \href{}{} in the text, instead of writing them myself.

e.g.:

```
\href{www.example.com}{example 1}, \href{www.something.com}{example 2} to \href{www.different.com}{example x}
```

will return **example 1**, **example 2** to **example x**, but I want to have a command to have them being written as sequential numbers automatically without me writing their labels as **[1]**, **[2]** to **[x]**

Comment: you want sequential numbers in the DNS name as well ? (I assume you want `https://www.example1.com` not just ww.example,com ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as **example1** would be a hyperlink for `https://www.example1.com`, I only want hyperlinks to be in sequential order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

From

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{ex}
\newcommand\exref{%
  \stepcounter{ex}%
  \href{https://www.example\theex.com}{example \theex}}

\begin{document}

\exref, \exref, \exref.

\end{document}
```

Or with the URL as argument:

[image]

from

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{ex}
\newcommand\exref{%
  \stepcounter{ex}%
  \href{https://www.example\theex.com}{example \theex}}

\newcommand\exrefb[1]{%
  \stepcounter{ex}%
  \href{#1}{example \theex}}

\begin{document}

\exref, \exref, \exref.

\exrefb{https://www.example1.com},
\exrefb{https://www.example.com},
\exrefb{https://www.stackexchange.com}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. However, I am using different DNS for each example...

Comment: @robmiller505 well that is exactly why I asked under your question whether you had sequential DNS names, it seemed unuusal but not impossible (especially on an intranet) and I took your reply as meaning "yes", just add an argument tp `\exref` aand then use `\href{#1}{example \theex}`

Comment: @robmiller505 answer updated

Comment: thank you for your helpful input